# Can you use Power Automate with SharePoint to create a work flow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, power-automate

I'm working on a project where a request system needs to be designed on SharePoint. I want to use Power Automate with SharePoint to create a work flow, where based on the attached email, key words can be read and the appropriate documents can be sent for the product of interest.

Can something like this be designed?

Based on the videos I've seen on YouTube and templates available, I feel like I could do this but haven't found a template that matches exactly what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this would be possible. You could create an array with a mapping. Where every keyword matches a certain pdf file. Whenever a new e-mail arrives you could check if one of the keywords is part of the body/body.

I have attached a screenshot which has a simple version of this approach. It will sent a reply per keyword:
[Match keyword in body and sent reply with attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD3i6.png)

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot and the explaination. I appreciate it. If the email didn't have any identifiable keywords would there be a way to have that request be sent to a group mailbox? I'm asking to make sure that I am cover all possibilites with the design. Thank you!